# Cannot add new shared dataset to report

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a summary report with about 20 datasets, linking to 20 detail sub-reports.

I have added datasets based on stored procedures for each of the detail reports.

Now when I try to add another one I get an error message

> Could not create a list of fields for the query. Verify that you can connect to the data source and that your query syntax us correct.

and in the *details* it states:

> An item with the same key has already been added.

So I have executed the stored procedure in SQL Server, no problems. I have executed the stored procedure in the Query Designer in SSRS, and it works fine.

I have restarted VS 2013, and reloaded the project. 
The project rebuilds with no errors. 
The report(s) deploy to the report server with no issues or errors.

Is there something else I can do to clean out the project file? I need to be able to include these extra datasets.

Comment: Maybe you have two columns with the same name in your new datasets?

Comment: @JoaoLeal: No, it wouldn't compile as a stored proc in SQL Server, or execute in the Query Designer...

Comment: Why not? Stored procedures can have select statements with columns with the same names (Views can't)

Comment: @JoaoLeal: True, I will try editing the stored proc to only show a few fields, and see what happens

Comment: @JoaoLeal: LOL, it works with the just the key fields, now have to add them one by one to see which one is causing the problem in SSRS but not in SQL Server!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason for this error is that your stored procedure returns a table which has duplicated field names.

Just double check that all the field names are unique, and it should work.

Comment: it was one column duplicated, I hadn't considered that this was a likelihood!